# In Matlab, how to call GUI callback functions without the GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I am not a GUI programmer, as will become obvious.  If anything, I'm trying to unmake a GUI.  I am using a program called art (found [here](https://www.nitrc.org/projects/artifact_detect/), if it's useful to see) that generates figures and variables that I would like to save.  You can call art from a batch script and make it read a config file for its inputs, which is what I'm doing, but you have to manually generate and save much of its output (variables and figures) in the GUI.  I'd love to automate this process, but I am really struggling.

I think the core of my issue would be solved if I knew how to force the callback functions to be called.  For instance, there is a function in art `showCorr_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)` (which is governed by a radio button in the GUI). It has a test condition to execute:

`if (get(handles.showCorr,'Value') == get(handles.showCorr,'Max'))`

I've tried inserting

```
mx = get(handles.showCorr,'Max')) 
setappdata(handles.showCorr,'Value', mx)
```

into a function I know executes, the opening function, `function art_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)`.  That doesn't seem to have any effect.  If I knew how to make the callback functions execute, perhaps I could insert the code that saves the figure into the functions.  Somewhere in Matlab's GUI scripts there must be something that is continually testing for a change in state in the GUI.  Where is that thing?  How can I fool it into thinking a radio button has been pressed?

Thanks for your help, and please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to set the `Value` of `handles.showCorr`, you won't use [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) as that just stores arbitrary data (by key/value pair) into the graphics object. You actually want to set the [`Value` *property*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_value).

```
set(handles.showCorr, 'Value', get(handles.showCorr, 'Max'))
```

This should trigger any callbacks that are assigned to `handles.showCorr`.

If, for some reason this doesn't trigger the callback, you can always trigger it manually. If you already know the callback, you can call it explicitly.

```
showCorr_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I'm upvoting your answer but not accepting it, because it was a helpful but partial answer.  Your hgfeval line threw an exception.  What worked was using `set(handles.showCorr, 'Value', get(handles.showCorr, 'Max'))` and then explicitly calling the function with `showCorr_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles);`.  It seems kind of silly in retrospect that I didn't do that sooner, but I was confused about what arguments it took.  Only a lot of poking around in the debugger revealed to me that the arguments it needed had the same name as in the function definition.

Comment: @Katie what was the error? Also you can definitely do it the way you did and I can add it to the answer for completeness.

Comment: @Katie I believe that I have updated my answer so now *both* should work. Can you check the first for me?

Comment: As written, there's a typo and you mean 'hObject', right? -- here's the trace:

`Error using guidata (line 87)
H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent.

Error in hgfeval (line 64)
        evalin('base', fcn);

Error in ks_art>art_OpeningFcn (line 564)
hgfeval(get(handles.showCorr, 'Callback'), hObject, [], handles)

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 220)
    feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure),
    varargin{:});

Error in ks_art (line 130)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ks_art_batch (line 98)
        ks_art('sess_file',cfgfile);`

Comment: (If I do it with 'hobject' I get `Undefined function or variable 'hobject'.`)

Comment: @Katie thanks for the feedback. I've updated it to just use the standard `feval`. Can you try that, maybe? The nice thing about the `feval` approach is that it works regardless of *what* the callback is so you can use the same logic to execute *any* callback and you don't have to know what the callback actually is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105944/discussion-between-katie-and-suever).